# is SSL encryption done automatically?

Tags: rest, cordova, ssl

I am new to SSL.
Right now I am developing an cordova mobile application.

According to digicert tutorial, there are 5 steps for ssl handshake(? I am not sure if this is right terminology)

1. Browser connects to a web server (website) secured with SSL (https). Browser requests that the server identify itself.
2. Server sends a copy of its SSL Certificate, including the server’s public key.
3. Browser checks the certificate root against a list of trusted CAs and that the certificate is unexpired, unrevoked, and that its common name is valid for the website that it is connecting to. If the browser trusts the certificate, it creates, encrypts, and sends back a symmetric session key using the server’s public key.
4. Server decrypts the symmetric session key using its private key and sends back an acknowledgement encrypted with the session key to start the encrypted session.
5. Server and Browser now encrypt all transmitted data with the session key.

I am trying to send a request to a backend server which is secured with SSL. Is there any extra step that I have to implement in order to do steps 1-5 or is all I have to do changing the url from http to https? If I send a request to https://url, Are steps 1-5 going to be done automatically?

Comment: Most if not every web client (or whatever you call it) will handle this for you, by specification.

Comment: TLS is explained in great detail here: https://tls.ulfheim.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL Handshake steps you have explained are perfect and in a proper queue. You do not need to implement any extra step.

The SSL Handshake process will be held between the browser and server, If the genuine SSL installed properly in the server, the browser will complete the handshake process without falling for any error.